# Library to simulate weld bead placement in an uneven weld

Tags: c++, c#, simulation, planning

I am doing simulations into weld planning. I am looking into a library (c++ or c# related) which can place simple shapes (e.g. rectangles) into a simple cross-section geometry.

[image]

For example, given a specified outline (v-like shape), I want to place rectangle blocks of a variable width and height (blocks 1, 2, 3) within these outlines to fill it up.

The closest library I can find are those related to the problem of sphere/circle packing; but those are usually packed inside a cube/box, rather than inside an arbitrary shape.